# How to properly chain, and access css elements with many divs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors

I know it's a basic and deprecated question, and I've already found some valuable info about it, but my example still doesn't work. I use bootstrap css, and html.

My main problem, I can't properly chain the elements in css, so there's no effect on the elements. In this case I want to reach the "icon-bar" calss to make it white.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand"></a><img class="img-responsive" 
    src="img/mainicon.png" width="50" height="50" alt="main"/>
     </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#about">RÓLUNK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">SZOLGÁLTATÁSOK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">MUNKÁINK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing">AJÁNLATOK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">KAPCSOLAT</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

Here's an example where css can't find input[type=text]. I assume it's because of the unproper accessing.

```
   <div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
     <h2 class="text-center">Kapcsolat</h2>
      <div class="row slideanim">
       <div class="col-sm-5">
         <p>Lépjen velünk kapcsolatba, és mi 24 órán belül válaszolunk.</p>
         <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Budapest, 
         Magyarország</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> 06-30-760-1018</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> 
        info@sethdevelop.hu</p>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-7">
      <div class="row slideanim">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Név/Cégnév" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Komment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Küldés</button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  outline: none;
  }

  input[type=text]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #555;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily access the icon-bar with this CSS code

see snippet or > [jsfilddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/DTcHh/33004/)

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 background-color:white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand"></a><img class="img-responsive" 
    src="img/mainicon.png" width="50" height="50" alt="main"/>
     </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#about">RÓLUNK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">SZOLGÁLTATÁSOK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">MUNKÁINK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pricing">AJÁNLATOK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">KAPCSOLAT</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

as for the input, it works well. You should try to use more specific selectors if it still doesn't work , like instead of `input[type="text"]` use `#contact .form-group input[type="text"]{}`

Comment: glad i could help :D